# update view at 5hz: surfaceview or view?

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-canvas, surfaceview

A ble peripherall send to me data at 5hz, I receive it in a service then I send this data through "local broadcast msg" to ux at the same rateo after an interpolation.

On the UX I have to draw a custom indicator with this rateo.

I think to use surfaceview but I'm wondering if normal view extension is enough.

Can you give me some suggestion ?

Comment: `5 Hz` is actually 5 ticks per second (`200 ms`). I guess that a View is able to display data at such a low rate.

Comment: which is the rate limit for a View ?

Comment: It possibly depends on your GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no fixed rate limit for custom Views.

If you were planning to render with Canvas, then a [custom View](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) will probably be more efficient than a SurfaceView, because it can take advantage of [hardware acceleration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html).  Canvas rendering onto a SurfaceView Surface is always done in software (as of 5.0 at least).

The advantage of the Surface is that, because it's on a separate layer, you're not tied to the View UI's invalidate/redraw cycle.

At five updates per second I think you have a pretty free hand in choosing a solution.